# Have GDB show the type of a template argument

Tags: c++, templates, gdb

Let's say I'm running GDB on a complicated piece of templated C++ code, and I want to know what types are in the current instanciation ... for example:

```
template <typename T>
void foo ()
{
/// I've got a breakpoint in here somewhere.
}
```

So I hit my breakpoint, and I want to know what type T is.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just type `frame` in gdb prompt:

```
(gdb) frame
```

The function name along with template argument will be printed in the first line of output. See [online doc](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Selection.html):

> All of these commands end by printing two lines of output describing
>   the frame. The first line shows the frame number, the function name,
>   the arguments, and the source file and line number of execution in
>   that frame. The second line shows the text of that source line.

Answer (score 7):

If your compiler emits proper debugging information for template parameters (for non-variadic templates, gcc has done this for several years), you can just reference `T` as if it were an ordinary type, e.g. with `ptype`.

I tried this test program:

```
template<typename T>
T f()
{
  return 23;
}

int main()
{
  return f<int>();
}
```

Compiled with `-g` and set a breakpoint inside `f`:

```
(gdb) b 4
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4005c5: file q.cc, line 4.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/q 

Breakpoint 1, f<int> () at q.cc:4
4     return 23;
(gdb) ptype T
type = int
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I do that?

This will give you mangled name of the current symbol:

```
(gdb) info symbol $pc
```

This will give you demangled name:

```
(gdb) main demangle symbol_name
(gdb) shell c++filt symbol_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also break using regexp as follows:

```
(gdb) rbreak foo<.*>()
```

This can also be applied to templated class methods

```
(gdb) rbreak MyClass<.*>::my_method()
```